# Terminal command line - Dungas-iPhone

Tags: macos, terminal

Recently the following has appeared on my MacOS Terminal. I'm relatively new to using Terminal and have installed various bits of software lately, but cannot find any reference to this anywhere. My name is not Dungas, my iPhone isn't called Dungas and i'm pretty confused by this. Any ideas anyone?

> Last login: Thu Apr 30 13:59:40 on ttys000 
>   brettmoreton@Dungas-iPhone ~ %

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you executed some script or tried to run some command from any tutorial that caused this.

You can revert it back. Change `newname` to whatever value you want and you are good to go.

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "newname"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "newname"
sudo scutil --set HostName "newname"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but it hasn't worked :-(